# CruiseControl.NET multiple build servers authentication

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have CCNET 1.8.5.0 installed on two build servers and I configured WebDashboard on one server to [monitor both of them](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/RemoteServices). But it leads to such bug: when user logs in to one of the servers, webdashboard shows him as being authorized on other server too (Logout button is showed instead of Login). But when it tries to access project on second server he gets usual error:

*Request processing has failed on the remote server: Permission to execute 'ViewProject' has been denied.*

How could I force webdashboard to separate authorization on every server?

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a bug :-(

there is no configuration to my knowledge that would bypass this problem for the moment.

Comment: I wonder, if cc.net has active support community, which I can address bugs and await its fix?